# Scraping with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

what is wrong in my code, I try get the same content like in https://koleo.pl/rozklad-pkp/krakow-glowny/radom/19-03-2019_10:00/all/EIP-IC--EIC-EIP-IC-KM-REG but result is diffrent as I want to have.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'})
response=s.get('https://koleo.pl/rozklad-pkp/krakow-glowny/radom/19-03- 
2019_10:00/all/EIP-IC--EIC-EIP-IC-KM-REG')

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Output with prices, I wanna have the same content as you can see if click on link.

Comment: I have to set wait until content isn't load but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requests and pass params in to get json for the train info and prices. I haven't parsed out all the info as this is just to show you it is possible. I parse out the train ids to be able to make the subsequent requests from price info which are linked by ids to the train info

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://koleo.pl/pl/connections/?'

headers = {
    'Accept' : 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie' : '_ga=GA1.2.2048035736.1553000429; _gid=GA1.2.600745193.1553000429; _gat=1; _koleo_session=bkN4dWRrZGx0UnkyZ3hjMWpFNGhiS1I3TzhQMGNyWitvZlZ0QVRUVVVtWUFPMUwxL0hJYWJyYnlGTUdHYXNuL1N6QlhHMHlRZFM3eFZFcjRuK3ZubllmMjdSaU5CMWRBSTFOc1JRc2lDUGV0Y2NtTjRzbzZEd0laZWI1bjJoK1UrYnc5NWNzZzNJdXVtUlpnVE15QnRnPT0tLTc1YzV1Q2xoRHF4VFpWWTdWZDJXUnc9PQ%3D%3D--3b5fe9bb7b0ce5960bc5bd6a00bf405df87f8bd4',
    'Host' : 'koleo.pl',
    'Referer' : 'https://koleo.pl/rozklad-pkp/krakow-glowny/radom/19-03-2019_10:00/all/EIP-IC--EIC-EIP-IC-KM-REG',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36',
    'X-CSRF-Token' : 'heag3Y5/fh0hyOfgdmSGJBmdJR3Perle2vJI0VjB81KClATLsJxFAO4SO9bY6Ag8h6IkpFieW1mtZbD4mga7ZQ==',
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'

}
params = {
    'v' : 'a0dec240d8d016fbfca9b552898aba9c38fc19d5',
    'query[date]' : '19-03-2019 10:00:00',
    'query[start_station]' : 'krakow-glowny',
    'query[end_station]': 'radom',
    'query[brand_ids][]' : '29',
    'query[brand_ids][]' : '28',
    'query[only_direct]' : 'false',
    'query[only_purchasable]': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    data= s.get(url, params = params, headers = headers).json()
    print(data)
    priceUrl = 'https://koleo.pl/pl/prices/{}?v=a0dec240d8d016fbfca9b552898aba9c38fc19d5'
    for item in data['connections']:
        r = s.get(priceUrl.format(item['id'])).json()
        print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `selenium` in order to get that dynamically generated content. And then you can parse html with BS. For example I've parsed dates:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://koleo.pl/rozklad-pkp/krakow-glowny/radom/19-03-2019_10:00/all/EIP-IC--EIC-EIP-IC-KM-REG')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
for div in soup.findAll("div", {"class": 'date custom-panel'}):
    date = div.findAll("div", {"class": 'row'})[0].string.strip()
    print(date)
```

Output:

```
wtorek, 19 marca
środa, 20 marca
```